# Cannot connect to IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I have two Windows 10 machines. One I can start up a debug session by selecting of typing F5 and the other gives me a message that I cannot connect to IIS Express.

Starting up the debugger on the machine that doesn't work shows:

Starting IIS Express ...
Successfully registered URL "https://localhost:44342/" for site "BSoftSolutions" application "/"
Registration completed for site "BSoftSolutions"
IIS Express is running.
Failed to register URL "http://localhost:51136/" for site "BSoftSolutions" application "/". Error description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x80070020)

I have been unable to find the differences in these two machines that would cause Visual Studio to fail to connect to IIS?

[image]

I install jexus and ran a project diagnostic which gave me this report

```
IMPORTANT: This report might contain confidential information. Mask such before sharing to others.
-----
Scan the folder C:\Users\RKevi\Source\Repos\BSoftSolution\BSoftSolutions for project files.
1 project(s) are detected.
* BSoftSolutions.csproj


Project file: C:\Users\RKevi\Source\Repos\BSoftSolution\BSoftSolutions\BSoftSolutions.csproj.
IIS Express configuration file: C:\Users\RKevi\source\repos\BSoftSolution\.vs\BSoftSolutions\config\applicationHost.config.
Analyze ASP.NET Core project.
Visual Studio launchSettings.json: C:\Users\RKevi\Source\Repos\BSoftSolution\BSoftSolutions\Properties\launchSettings.json.
Extract debugging profiles.
Found 2 profile(s).
* IIS Express
* BSoftSolutions


Extract IIS settings.
sslPort is 44342.
applicationUrl is http://localhost:51136.
Binding localhost on *:51136 (http).
Binding localhost on *:44342 (https).
A matching binding is found for https://localhost:44342/.
```

Comment: Run basic diagnostics to check the relevant settings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Comment: jexusmanager is an application that I need? The tutorial seems out of date. There isn't an 'applicationHost.config' file and there isn't a mention of IIS in the .csproj file. Since I am not using Visual Studio Code I also don't have a launchsettings.json.

Comment: The documentation for jexus mentions "Opening a web site with Jexus". I am not sure how to do this?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-solution-file

Comment: I am to the 4 page of "getting started". So far I don't see an option to "Run Diagnostics" so I can see why I cannot connect to IIS?

Comment: You need to finish the connection wizard so as to let Jexus Manager connect to the IIS Express server configuration. Once you see the server added, expand the sites, and that menu item is at site level in Actions panel.

Comment: I found the diagnostics (ASP.NET Core diagnostics) but I sill don't see information in the report that tells me why I cannot connect to IIS. I could give you the diagnostics but it makes this comment too long.

Comment: That does not apply to your case. You need Visual Studio Project Diagnostics.

Comment: Running the project diagnostics gives me

Extract IIS settings.
sslPort is 44342.
applicationUrl is http://localhost:51136.
Binding localhost on *:51136 (http).
Binding localhost on *:44342 (https).
A matching binding is found for https://localhost:44342/.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the report. Comments are not for that purpose.